# Decision tree vs Naive Bayes vs KNN

Tags: algorithm, decision-tree, knn, naivebayes

When data mining, when should you choose one of these algorithms over the other? Is there a specific reason? Also which one of these is the most efficient?

I'm going to give a table for example purposes.
[image]

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that KNN out of the three would have the longest running time?

Answer (score 2):

One way to choose would be to try all of them and pick the best.

If I was to try and construct data to favour one or the other, here is what I might do.

1) To favour decision trees, have only a few attributes determine the correct answer, with all the others useless distractions.

2) To favour Naive Bayes, construct 2n+1 attributes by choosing at random either n 1s and n+1 -1s or n+1 1s and n -1s and assigning them to attributes at random. Make the right answer be whether the bare majority is for +1 or -1.

3) To favour kNN, use two dimensional data and draw a broad spiral pattern of 1s in a background of 0s, with about equal numbers of 0s or 1s. The right answer is whether you are on a 0 or a 1.

kNN will certainly take up more memory at the time you are making decisions, as you have to remember all the instances instead of boiling them down into weights and tree rules. I would also expect it to take more time at decision time, although there are libraries to attempt to speed this up. Naive Bayes is probably the fastest and smallest.

There are a huge number of different ways to use decision trees, and some very sophisticated developments of it, such as random forests, which could take a noticeable amount of time and memory, but might do better on some data.